# nginx wordpress rewrite rule conflicted with stub_status module

Tags: nginx, wordpress, rewrite

i'm got a problem when i was trying to enable stub_status module on my wordpress based site.
the following is my configuration in nginx.conf.

```
location /status {
stub_status on;
access_log off;
}
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

my problem is i can access the status page if i remove the wordpress rewrite rule. if the rewrite rule exist, the status page not works. does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Don't use "(if !-e ...)", use try_files.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your rewrite belongs to `server` section, so there's no chance for `location /status`. So, all you need is to put your rewrite condition into other `location`.
P.S. I'm not sure that this is working config, but I think, that idea is delivered.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myserver.com;

  location /status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~* \.(ico|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|js|css)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location ~* (!\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png|css|js))$ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^/$ /index.php last;
    }
  }
}
```